# Android Studio SQLite no such column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to use a SQLite database with a string inside. The problem is, whenever I try to access it, I have the following error:

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column:
> Grid_ChallengeId (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Grid_Id,
> Grid_Name, Grid_Width, Grid_ChallengeId FROM Grid WHERE Grid_Id=?

There is my database:

```java
// Create table
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.i(TAG, "MyDatabaseGrille.onCreate ... ");
    // Script.
    String script = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_GRID + "("
            + COLUMN_GRID_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + COLUMN_GRID_TITLE + " TEXT,"
            + COLUMN_GRID_WIDTH + " INTEGER, "
            + COLUMN_GRID_CHALLENGEID + " TEXT "
            +")";

    // Execute Script.
    db.execSQL(script);
}
```

The line where the error may occur:

```java
public Grid getGrid(int id) {
    Log.i(TAG, "MyDatabaseGrille.getGrid ... " + id);

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_GRID, new String[] { COLUMN_GRID_ID,
                    COLUMN_GRID_TITLE, COLUMN_GRID_WIDTH, COLUMN_GRID_CHALLENGEID }, COLUMN_GRID_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Grid grid = new Grid(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)), cursor.getString(3) );
    // return grid
    return grid;
}
```

and the error in the logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.soireebingov6, PID: 23983
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.soireebingov6/com.example.soireebingov6.AffichageGrille}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Grid_ChallengeId (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Grid_Id, Grid_Name, Grid_Width, Grid_ChallengeId FROM Grid WHERE Grid_Id=?
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2377)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1342)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5360)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Grid_ChallengeId (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT Grid_Id, Grid_Name, Grid_Width, Grid_ChallengeId FROM Grid WHERE Grid_Id=?
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:893)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:504)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1186)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1057)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1263)
        at database.MyDatabaseGrille.getGrid(MyDatabaseGrille.java:130)
        at com.example.soireebingov6.AffichageGrille.onCreate(AffichageGrille.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5343)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2331)
```

Comment: Open Device File Manager, go to "/data/data/<your_package_id>/databases/", click rmb on your database file and save as everywhere you want. Download and use SQLite Studio to open your databse file, and check what's wrong. I think you created table first without that column, but you didn't upgrade table after that. Add drop table command, override `onUpgrade()` method, call both commands inside: drop table first, then create it again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was exactly what i did ! It's the first time a people answer me without looking down on me cause I'm a new android dev. Thanks a lot

Comment: `onUpgrade` will call, when you increase a database version.

Comment: What your DB is created ?? You have checked that using Database inspector.